# Flex element not filling up 100% height in flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following markup:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}

.col1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}

.col2 {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
</div>
```

And I'm expecting it to look like this:

[image]

But instead when rendered in the browser and inspected, the height of `.col1` is `0px`. I'd expect it to be `200px` since `.col2` stretches the height of the container to that size. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` from `.col1`, like:

```
.col1 {
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
}
.col1 {
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
}
.col2 {
    background: blue;
    flex: 1;
    height: 200px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Easy solution. Add that height percentage only takes the height of the parent.

Comment: Unbelievable! Thanks for the help man :)

Comment: @Tiwaz89 It's my pleasure. Please support my answer by accepting it.